# How to exclude multiple branches in subgit when there is no same pattern

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I am using subgit's one time conversion from svn to git. The import approach I took was running configuration command(`subgit config svn_url`) then change config file (`/generated_repo.git/subgit/config`) and run import.

`excludeBranches` option in config file ask for a pattern. but in my scenario I don't have a common pattern for the branches that I want to exclude. So in my case I need to specify branch by branch. How can I create a pattern including every branch that I need to exclude for the `excludeBranches`option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried including multiple `excludeBranches` with exact branch name needed to  be excluded. it seems it do the job.

`[svn]
    url = https://.....
    ... # Other options
    ...
    excludeBranches = branches/branch_1
    excludeBranches = branches/branch_2
    excludeBranches = branches/branch_3
    .....`

Comment: Good catch. I missed that in the documentation. +1

Comment: @VonC actually I didn't find this in the documentation. while I browsing I found this [https://ask.helplib.com/git/post_4713959](https://ask.helplib.com/git/post_4713959). So I thought to try that out and it worked :).

Comment: I don't know Chinese either ;) . google translate did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html#10), you don't.
At best, you can try and use both `excludeBranches` and `excludeTags`, to have *two* patterns.

But once you have excluded the most important branches, the rest gets imported in the Git repository, and needs to be [deleted in the Git repo](https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/branching/delete-branch/) after import.